# LXD Containers and Host on DHCP

Tags: 16.04, networking, lxc, lxd

I'm working on containers at the moment and having trouble with configuring them to use the network's DHCP, so that they can be accessed via hostname (container name) directly. This'll mean apps on other devices can access the services on the container, and if I want to SSH to the container I don't need to firstly SSH to the host, and use lxc exec [containername] bash.

I've managed to successfully create a Ubuntu 16.04 container, and it runs fine. It runs within the IP range initially configured when I used lxd init though (10.0.1.*), however, i'd like to get them to use the main network's IP range and DHCP.

I managed to do this by adding to my /etc/network/interfaces file the following:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.64
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254

bridge_ports enp3s0  
iface enp3s0 inet manual
```

After reloading the networking service this worked fine, and the containers could be seen on the network, and vice versa. However, the host instead lost access to the internet and could not longer see other devices on the network and vice versa.

Reverting the changes gave the host machine access to the network again, however, the containers then returned to their original IP range, and with no visibility of the network.

I had further tinkerings, but to no success, so I'm back to the host having internet, and the containers not visible at the moment; this isn't what I want.

Can anyone provide any further insight onto where I might have gone wrong? Should I be doing something completely different?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does https://bayton.org/docs/linux/lxd/lxd-zfs-and-bridged-networking-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/ help? Note that you should verify `lxd --version`, whether it's higher than 2.5.

Comment: I'll have a look tonight, I haven't had a chance to physically get the the host yet. It is, however, running lxd 2.0.10, not 2.5.

Comment: No, as with every other guide I've used, as soon as I set up the bridge and restart/reload the networking service the host loses all connectivity. Sometimes the containers will have connectivity, sometimes not.

I'm beginning to think that this is an impossible task, and that only a host or containers can be on the same network... A real shame, and incredibly frustrating... VMs seem to work a lot better, but require more resources, so I'm not entertaining it...

Comment: No, mine certainly use the same DHCP server as their host, and are all accessible on the same network. I'm on Xenial also, so same `lxd` version. Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd` to setup the network after setting up the bridge as described in the article. Also, I set up the bridge using DHCP (so only `bridge_ports` directive under it), and relied on MAC to instruct the DHCP server to set a static IP.

Comment: I'm give reconfigure another go tonight. I am tempted to do a fresh install of the OS anyway, in all honesty. I've re-purposed the PC from a media Centre to a Development Environment, sometimes it's much easier to just start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end, the only thing that seemed to fix it was a fresh OS install. I'm now running Ubuntu 17.10. Rather than upgrading, I installed fresh (but made an image of my old install, should I need it).

As for the /etc/network/interfaces file, it was as simple as:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp

bridge_ports enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual
```

As for the lxd profile, it's configured as:

```
config: {}
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
name: default
```

Really not sure why it refused to work on 16.04.3 LTS, but at least it's working on 17.10.

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just so it's all written down together, in my setup all containers and their host machine get their IP from the same DHCP server (my router's), and are all available over the LAN.

On an Ubuntu Server 16.04 host, my `/etc/network/interfaces` reads:

```
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

As I said in comments, after a restart and when the host's network works as intended, I think you can reconfigure LXD's network (among other things) with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd`.

When I did `lxd init`, I answered `yes` to `Do you want to configure the LXD bridge (yes/no)?`, then told it `<No>` when it asked to setup a network bridge, `<Yes>` I would like to use an existing one, and `br0` as the bridge name.

Finally, I rely on MAC's to assign static IP's to any machine (including the host and several containers), in my DHCP server's (my router's) settings. This simplifies settings in the containers and host.